# What to read when bored?

Tags: blogs

Hey guys... Its quite late in the night right now and I'm taking some time off from coding my project. I discovered Coding Horror only a few weeks ago and I totally loved it. Having read all of its posts I have ran out of things to read when bored.

Can someone please suggest some great blogs (coding,computers) to read which are informative and fun one can read when bored?

Comment: Ever read the [DailyWTF](http://www.thedailywtf.com/)? It's funny, but take it all with a grain of salt.

Comment: There's 163 suggestions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78955/what-are-the-best-programming-and-development-related-blogs-closed

Comment: Belongs to: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I browsed through my RSS feeds and grabbed out this selection.

Regular updates:

- http://slashdot.org/ - Hopefully no
  comment necessary.  I read it for the
  comments, not the articles.
- http://thedailywtf.com/ - More for
  the amusement factor than for any
  self-improvement benefit.
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/ - Often short updates, often technical, but I find I really enjoy
  Raymond's blogging style.
- http://www.paulgraham.com/articles.html - Not updated daily, but very interesting backlog of essays.  Most
  recent updates focus on venture
  capital since that's where Paul works
  these days, but earlier essays are
  varied in focus.
- http://martinfowler.com/bliki/ -
  Similar to the previous one, sporadic
  updates but entries are generally
  well worth reading, especially if
  you're interested in Agile
  development.

Few or no updates, but great material to go through over time:

- http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/ -
  Amusing (and long) "rants", generally
  with a technology focus.
- http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/ - Interesting write-ups of technical problems and how they were solved
  using SysInternal tools. 
  Windows-oriented.

Answer (score 1):

This Site is great. I recommend :)

Answer (score 1):

Something comedic?
   Try Linux Hater's blog (http://linuxhaters.blogspot.com/).

Something educational?
   Try Jon Skeet's coding blog (http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/Default.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

[reddit.com](http://www.reddit.com) you will get hooked.

Answer (score 0):

[Steve Yegge](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/)'s and [Joel Spolsky](http://joelonsoftware.com)'s blogs have great stuff.